# rabbitmq command breaks all pip install

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, rabbitmq

New to MQTT and Linux world.
I am following [this link](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#apt) to set up my Mqtt broker on Raspberry Pi 4.

after running this command

```
# import PackageCloud signing key
wget -O - "https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/gpgkey" | sudo apt-key add -
```

and followed its [instruction](https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/install#bash-python), I ran this:

```
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/script.python.sh | bash
```

All my pip install are failing.

for example:

```
$ pip3 install PyMail
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/pypi/simple
Collecting PyMail
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/pypi/simple/pymail/
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Just undo what the first command did? Sorry, but that seems to be the obvious answer, so maybe you could describe why that isn't suitable for you? In any case, that doesn't seem to be a programming question but one of system administration and/or installing regular software.

Comment: thanks @UlrichEckhardt I don't know how to do the 1st command. could you please elaborate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to remove my pip3 and re-install it.

Surprisingly, even after removal and re-installation, the error is still there~!!!

---

This is how I solved this problem:

I opened the pip configuration file which is located:(depending on different OS, the file could locate at different place. Mine is Raspbian Buster 10)

> $HOME/.pip/pip.conf

In its content I saw this:

```
[global]
extra-index-url=https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/pypi/simple
```

then I removed the packagecloud url and restarted my terminal.

problem solved.

I think some scripts in this file:
https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/script.python.sh

modified the pip config

Answer (score 0):

follow this link, complete and working commands for rmq setup:
And you can use pika for connecting ur rmq via python

```
https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-latest-erlang-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-latest-rabbitmq-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/
```